# Error al obtener varios resultados de una subconsulta - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero hacer una select, con 3 columnas, la primera es un *id*, la segunda es un *nombre*, y la tercera otro *nombre*.

El objetivo es obtener en una tabla final que ya tengo montada, una columna que contenga uno u otro nombre en función de si tienen algo o no para ese *id* definido.

Pseudocódigo:

```
select id, 
if(nombre1 is not null) entonces obtengo nombre1
else if (nombre2 is not null) entonces obtengo nombre2
else ''
```

He visto ejemplos con condiciones `CASE WHEN` y con `EXISTS`, pero no doy con ello. El primer nombre lo obtengo con esta consulta:

```
select [AM].[idAM], (select top 1 Responsable) GestorAM from [RegModifNRAM]
        inner join [AM] 
        on [AM].[idAM] = [RegModifNRAM].[idAM]
        inner join [AccionesRegModifCulture] 
        on AccionesRegModifCulture.idAccionesRegModif = [RegModifNRAM].[idAccion] and AccionesRegModifCulture.idCulture = 1
        INNER JOIN  Auditoria 
        ON [RegModifNRAM].idAuditoria = Auditoria.idAuditoria
        where [RegModifNRAM].[idAccion] in (50000,50023,50024,50026,50028,50030,50031,50036,50038,50039,50041,50044)
        order by [RegModifNRAM].[fx_Creacion] desc
```

...y el segundo nombre así:

```
    Select am.idam, 
( SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.apellido1, '') 
                                + ' ' 
                                + ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.apellido2, '') 
                                + ' ' 
                                + ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.nombre, '')))
  FROM  ResponsableAMPrivilegio
                LEFT JOIN Responsable
                    ON Responsable.idResponsable = ResponsableAMPrivilegio.idResponsable
                WHERE   (ResponsableAMPrivilegio.borrado = 0 OR ResponsableAMPrivilegio.borrado IS NULL)
                        AND ResponsableAMPrivilegio.idPrivilegio =  40 --P40    GESTOR SAM
                        and am.idam = ResponsableAMPrivilegio.idaccionmejora
                        AND ResponsableAMPrivilegio.idAccionMejora in (SELECT ID FROM #IDSENTIDADESeq)
) as 'GestorAM'
from AM
WHERE AM.idAM in (SELECT ID FROM #IDSENTIDADESeq)
```

Veo si puedo obtener un nombre en la primera consulta, si no puedo, veo en la segunda, pero si no, dejo `''`.

He estado mirando subconsultas dentro de condiciones `CASE`, y dentro de `IF..ELSE` para intentar obtenerlo, pero no lo consigo.

Pongo el ejemplo de las dos tablas y de lo que quiero conseguir:

Primera tabla:

```
idAM    Responsable 
5982    RAUL CORBELLA CARRASCO
6854    PEDRO JIMÉNEZ MARTÍN
8555    NULL
8556    NULL
```

Segunda tabla:

```
idAM    Responsable 
5982    NULL
6854    PEDRO JIMÉNEZ MARTÍN
8555    MARTÍN CEBALLOS
8556    NULL
```

De esta forma, el resultado en la tabla final sería algo así:

```
idAM    Columna1    ...    ...   Responsable              ...    ...    
5982    ...                      RAUL CORBELLA CARRASCO
6854    ...                      PEDRO JIMÉNEZ MARTÍN
8555    ...                      MARTÍN CEBALLOS
8556    ...                      NULL
```

Comment: Cuál es la diferencia entre ambas consultas?. Puedes poner algunos datos de prueba y el resultado que quieres obtener?

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta para ayudar a aclarar lo que quiero hacer. Espero que ahora esté más entendible. La idea es poder meter en una tabla temporal la columna Responsable ya con los nombres extraídos bien, para poder hacer un JOIN con la tabla final y que dé como resultado el ejemplo final que he puesto. Lo que pensé es hacer una select y usar CASE WHEN o IFs para sacarlo, pero no he conseguido dar con la solución..

Comment: @daniellozano ¿podrías usar [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para crear un ejemplo funcional?

Comment: No hace falta que indiques solucionado en el título de la pregunta. Aceptando la respuesta la gente ya sabe que esa respuesta es la que te ha resuelto el problema. O en su defecto, si has usado una respuesta propia puedes responder a la propia pregunta y aceptar tu respuesta (después de dos días).

Comment: @Error404 podrá aceptar su respuesta inmediatamente si la publica, pues el límite de aceptar una respuesta propia es de dos días desde que se publicó la pregunta.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, por supuesto, es dos días desde que publico la pregunta y si es así la puede aceptar inmediatamente. Como la he visto que había salido en el timeline pensaba que la había preguntado hoy. Muchas gracias por añadir eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Respuesta del autor de la pregunta que proporcionó en [una edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/35950/4) a la pregunta original.

Al final he utilizado la función que me habéis dicho y lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

Tengo 2 querys, en las que tengo que sacar de una tabla concreta un valor para cada una, y luego comprobar si la primera tiene valor. En caso de no tener valor, me quedo con la segunda. Mi solución (no sé si más o menos óptima, pero sí funcional) ha sido utilizar tablas temporales. He creado una tabla temporal para almacenar el resultado de la primera query, y otra tabla temporal para almacenar el resultado de la segunda. Luego, en una tercera tabla, utilizo la función ISNULL(valorTabla1 , valorTabla2) para comprobar el resultado de las dos tablas anteriores, quedando de la siguiente manera:

Creo mi tabla temporal principal, donde almacenaré el resultado de la comprobación:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA (idInformeSMA INT, Cargador varchar(4000))
```

Obtengo el valor de la primera query en la primera tabla temporal:

```
select [InformeSMA].idInformeSMA, [RegModifNRSMA].Responsable CargadorInformeSMA--,
into #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_LOG
    from [InformeSMA]
        left join [RegModifNRSMA] 
        on [InformeSMA].[idInformeSMA] = [RegModifNRSMA].[idSMA] and [RegModifNRSMA].[idAccion] in (20000)--,20005,20013,20014,20015,20016,30000)
        left join [AccionesRegModifCulture] 
        on AccionesRegModifCulture.idAccionesRegModif = [RegModifNRSMA].[idAccion] and AccionesRegModifCulture.idCulture = 1
        left JOIN   Auditoria 
        ON [RegModifNRSMA].idAuditoria = Auditoria.idAuditoria
        where [InformeSMA].[idInformeSMA] 
        in (SELECT ID FROM #IDSENTIDADESeq)
```

Obtengo el valor de la segunda query en la segunda tabla temporal:

```
 select InformeSMA.idInformeSMA,
(SELECT TOP 1   CASE WHEN Responsable.apellido2 like '%Delegado por%' OR Responsable.apellido2 like '%Simulado por%'

      THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.apellido1, '') +
                                ' ' 
                                + ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.apellido2, '') +
                                ' ' 
                                + ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.nombre, '')))
      ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.nombre, '') +
                                ' ' 
                                + ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.apellido1, '') +
                                ' ' 
                                + ISNULL(dbo.Responsable.apellido2, '')))
END
                FROM    ResponsableAuditoriaPrivilegio
                LEFT JOIN Responsable ON Responsable.idResponsable = ResponsableAuditoriaPrivilegio.idResponsable
                WHERE   ResponsableAuditoriaPrivilegio.idAuditoriaGama = InformeSMA.idInformeSMA
                        AND 
                        (ResponsableAuditoriaPrivilegio.borrado = 0 OR ResponsableAuditoriaPrivilegio.borrado IS NULL)
                        AND ResponsableAuditoriaPrivilegio.idPrivilegio = 26 --P26 - GESTOR INFORME SMA
                        ) as 'cargadorInforme'

into #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_PRIVILEGIO
from InformeSMA
WHERE InformeSMA.idInformeSMA
 in (SELECT ID FROM #IDSENTIDADESeq)
```

Utilizo la tabla principal para obtener el resultado deseado con la función ISNULL():

```
    INSERT INTO #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA
    select distinct #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_LOG.idInformeSMA,            isnull(#TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_LOG.CargadorInformeSMA,   #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_PRIVILEGIO.cargadorInforme)
from #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_PRIVILEGIO
inner join #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_LOG on #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_LOG.idInformeSMA = #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_PRIVILEGIO.idInformeSMA
where #TABLA_CARGADOR_INFORMESMA_LOG.idInformeSMA 
in (SELECT ID FROM #IDSENTIDADESeq)
```

Para finalizar, si hago un select * de la tabla temporal principal, obtengo el resultado esperado. Aunque no se entienda qué hace cada una de las querys, espero que se entienda el procedimiento que he seguido para obtener mi solución y que pueda ayudar a la gente.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas para nada hacer una subconsulta en este caso, un simple `JOIN` es más que suficiente:

```
SELECT A.idAM, ISNULL(A.Responsable,B.Responsable) Responsable
FROM dbo.Tabla1 A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Tabla2 B
    ON A.idAM = B.idAM;
```

Comment: Entiendo que de esta forma, si la primera consulta es nula, va a la segunda, y si ésta es nula, como dice Garrizano, puedo poner ' ' y que salga vacío y punto. El problema que tengo es que lo tengo que sacar en función del valor de otros campos de esa tabla. Por ejemplo:
select A.idAM, ISNULL(A.Responsable from dbo.TABLA1 A where A.campo1 = X and A.campo2 = Y, B.Responsable from dbo.TABLA2 B where B.campo1 = J and B.campo2 = K)
No sé si me explico. Desconocía esta función de is null, y no sé si puedo coger ese valor de A.Responsable metiendo esas condiciones para obtenerlo.

Comment: De alguna forma, al meter los valores que quiero obtener en el ISNULL(..), no sé si puedo meter esas condiciones que tengo puestas para cada uno de los dos valores o puedo adaptarla de alguna forma para meterla dentro del ISNULL. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de entender lo que deseas hacer, pero pensaría en algo con `ISNULL(expresion_a_evaluar, valor_de_reemplazo)`. En el primer parámetro podría ser la primero sub consulta y el segundo parámetro tu segunda sub consulta. Y pienso que serían dos `ISNULL` anidadas:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ISNULL(
        ISNULL(TU_PRIMER_SUB_CONSULTA, TU_SEGUNDA_SUB_CONSULTA), '') as RESPONSABLE
FROM
    TABLA_DE_DONDE_OBTIENES_EL_ID
```

Esa es mi idea, si es que te he entendido bien.

Saludos.

Comment: Sí! Es justo esa idea, solo que, como digo a Lamak justo arriba, esos valores de la primera consulta y la segunda no los obtengo directamente, sino que los obtengo en función de unas condiciones que pongo en los where en esas select que he puesto arriba. Tienes idea de si puedo adaptarlas para que se tengan en cuenta al hacer el ISNULL? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Yo digo que pongas esas dos consultas dentro del `ISNULL`, así completas.

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero me ha dado error por todos lados. Estoy probando es crear dos tablas temporales que contengan el valor y una tercera que utilice este {ISNULL} comprobando si hay valor en la primera tabla temporal y, si no, que vaya a la segunda. Lo que intenté con las consultas fué hacer algo tipo:
{SELECT idAM, (consulta1), (consulta2)} pero me daba errores tipo bound y cosas así. ¿Solo con meterlo en la consulta como digo sería suficiente, o a lo mejor estoy obviando algo al hacerlo? Desconozco si puedo meter una consulta completa con sus joins y todo..disculpad la inexperiencia =(

Comment: Sí, puedes colocar toda la consulta dentro, solo ten cuidado de colocarlo ordenadamente. Como son sub consultas, estas deben dentro de paréntesis: `ISNULL((SUB_CONSULTA_1), (SUB_CONSULTA_2))`. No te preocupes, con la experiencia uno va aprendiendo poco a poco; todo es cuestión de prueba y error :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias Garrizano!, vuestra ayuda me ha venido super bien. Os pongo cuál ha sido la solución que he encontrado y que me ha funcionado correctamente. Lo pongo en la consulta mía con la etiqueta de SOLUCIÓN.

Comment: @daniellozano si eso, añade otra respuesta o pide que se incluya en esta respuesta. La pregunta original debe ser eso, una _pregunta_.